# Wireless is disabled by hardware switch on Lenovo Z470

Tags: wireless, network-manager

My friend has been running Ubuntu 11.10 for quite some time. Everything had been working fine.

The laptop shut down because of battery and when rebooted, the wireless lan hasn't been working with a message "Wireless is disabled by hardware switch". He has checked that the hardware switch is indeed on.

The output of `rfkill list` is as follows:

```
 0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
 1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
 2: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

He even tried `rfkill unblock all` but `rfkill list` still showed `Hard blocked: yes` for phy0: Wireless LAN.

Following is the description of wireless interface returned by `lshw`:

```
 *-network DISABLED
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Centrino Wireless-N 1000
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
   logical name: wlan1
   version: 00
   serial: 74:e5:0b:0c:39:0e
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlagn driverversion=3.0.0-14-generic-pae firmware=128.50.3.1 build 13488 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:42 memory:e8100000-e8101fff
```

Just for the info, my friend doesn't have Windows on his machine.

Comment: can you please also include the **rfkill list** output?

Comment: I have edited the question to include the output of rfkill list.

Comment: you said in the question that the "hardware switch is on" - what happens if you turn it "off" ?

Comment: Tried even that. In that case, `rfkill list` shows Hard Blocked: yes for all entries.

Comment: can you also show     lsmod    output? I believe it has something to do with wmi module

Comment: Sorry, but he has already tried the method which I have described as an answer. Thanks for the help, anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My friend tried installing a new instance of Ubuntu but the problem persisted.

He, then, installed Windows along with the drivers. He activated wireless using key-combination `Fn+F5`. On installing Ubuntu this time, it worked.

Comment: where and when did he do fn+F5? During boot up?

Comment: He did it in Windows after it was installed.

Answer (score 0):

To fix Z470 WiFi:

1. List item
2. Reboot
3. [F2] and enter into BIOS
4. Set DEFAULTS
5. Save and restart
6. Done!

Source: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Z/probl...ght/true#M1096